# Why do I get "Associated reference no longer appears to be available"?

Tags: react-admin

I have explained whole issue here https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5142 . But as far as the stackoverflow community is more active, I mention the issue here too.

Please explain me, why this sample code is working properly

```
  <ReferenceInput label={"Specification"} perPage={20} source={"specificationName"}
                                    reference={ResourceNames.SPECIFICATIONS}>
                        <SelectInput optionText={"name"}/>
   </ReferenceInput>
```

while this code is showing the `"Associated reference no longer appears to be available"` error message.

```
  <ReferenceInput label={"Specification"} perPage={20} source={"specificationName"}
                                    reference={ResourceNames.SPECIFICATIONS}>
                        <SelectInput optionText={"name"} optionValue={"name"} />
   </ReferenceInput>
```

The only difference between above given examples - is the `optionValue` property passed to `SelectInput`. What's wrong with it? I don't want my `SelectInput` to use `ID` as a value... How the `optionValue` property is related to the above mentioned error message?

Please help! Thank you in advance

Comment: When I pass "id" in the `optionValue` property - error message disappears... I see no logic behind that. But I still need to pass `name` instead of `id`

Comment: I have same issue ```         <ReferenceInput
          source="variantId"
          reference="variants"
          filterToQuery={(searchText) => {
            name: searchText;
          }}
          fullWidth
        >
          <AutocompleteInput optionText="name" />
        </ReferenceInput>

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution. React-Admin requires the `id` for resources identification.

But if you need a custom identifier for your resource then have a look at the article below

See https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FAQ.html#can-i-have-custom-identifiersprimary-keys-for-my-resources

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur also if your model filter doesn't accept an `ids` attribute, observed in the web console.

I ended up in this situation because I based my schema off the schema provided in the readme of ra-data-graphql-simple.

To solve, I added the `ids` property to the type filter in the graphql schema.

PS - if you're bootstrapping like I was, it will be time to swap out the Edit and List Guessers for components that make use of a reference field